# probabilty problem how to solve

Tags: probability

Six cards are drawn with replacement form on ordinary deck. What is the probabilty that each of four suits will be represented at least once among the six cards?

Comment: When choosing a title, please consider that it's meant to identify the question on the main page. "problem how to solve" is redundant, since all questions here are about how to solve problems. The tags are visible wherever the title is visible, so merely repeating the tag "probability" in the title is also redundant. The title should summarize more specific information about the question, such as "four suits among six cards drawn with replacement".

Comment: jab usne edit de rakha hai to aap use edit kyu nahi kar dete.... @joriki

Comment: Unfortunately I don't speak the language you're using. For better or worse, the common language on this site is English; please write in English so I can understand you. If you feel unable to translate what you wrote into English, please indicate what language you're using so I can try to get it translated myself. Thanks.

Comment: ok,thanks... i'll consider this point whenever i'll ask any question.,,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that at most 3 suits are represented, is paradoxically given in such a situation by applying inclusion-exclusion, viz.

4*0.75^6 - 6*0.5^6 + 4*0.25^6 = 0.6191

and the indicated probability is thus

1 - 0.6191 = 0.3809

See the question "non-routine application of inclusion-exclusion" for a full discussion of this apparent paradox

Answer (score 2):

Consider the different cases:
**1 suit**
$$
\begin{align*}
P(\text{Only } \clubsuit \text{ suit is drawn}) &= \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{4}\end{pmatrix}^6\\
P(\text{Only } \heartsuit \text{ suit is drawn}) &= \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{4}\end{pmatrix}^6\\
P(\text{Only } \spadesuit \text{ suit is drawn}) &= \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{4}\end{pmatrix}^6\\
P(\text{Only } \diamondsuit \text{ suit is drawn}) &= \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{4}\end{pmatrix}^6
\end{align*}
$$
So 4 cases.

**2 suits**
$$
\begin{align*}
P(\text{Only } \clubsuit \text  { AND } \heartsuit \text{ suit is drawn}) &= \begin{pmatrix}\frac{2}{4}\end{pmatrix}^6 - 2\times \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{4}\end{pmatrix}^6\\
&.\\&.\\&.\\
\end{align*}
$$
The idea here is you EXCLUDE the cases where only $\clubsuit$ or $\heartsuit$ are chosen. The residual probability is the probability of **a combination of both $\clubsuit$ and $\heartsuit$

You will realize that there are ${4 \choose 2} = 6$ cases ie**

$$
(\clubsuit,\heartsuit) (\clubsuit,\spadesuit) (\clubsuit,\diamondsuit) \\
(\heartsuit,\spadesuit) (\heartsuit,\diamondsuit) (\spadesuit,\diamondsuit) 
$$

So do your multiplication accordingly.

3 suits
$$
\begin{align*}
P(\text{Only } \clubsuit \text  { AND } \heartsuit { AND } \spadesuit \text{ suit is drawn}) &= \begin{pmatrix}\frac{3}{4}\end{pmatrix}^6 - 3\times\begin{pmatrix}\frac{2}{4}\end{pmatrix}^6 - 3\times \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{4}\end{pmatrix}^6\\
&.\\&.\\&.\\
\end{align*}
$$

Similarly to 2 suits, the idea is to exclude the case where only 2 suits are selected, and only 1 suit is selected. There are $3$ ways that only 2 suits are selected and $3$ ways that only 1 suit can be selected.

There are 4 cases, namely
$$
(\clubsuit,\heartsuit, \spadesuit) (\heartsuit, \spadesuit, \diamondsuit) \\
(\spadesuit,\diamondsuit, \clubsuit) (\diamondsuit,\clubsuit, \heartsuit)
$$

So do the addition, and take compliment.
$$
\begin{align*}
\text{Req. Probability} &=
1\\&-
4\begin{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{4}\end{pmatrix}^6\end{bmatrix}\\&-
6\begin{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{2}{4}\end{pmatrix}^6 - 2\times \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{4}\end{pmatrix}^6\end{bmatrix}\\&-
4\begin{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{3}{4}\end{pmatrix}^6 - 3\times\begin{pmatrix}\frac{2}{4}\end{pmatrix}^6 + 3\times \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{4}\end{pmatrix}^6\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: thanks,got logic very clear but i'm not able get answer...

Comment: try the computation again?

Comment: the last term in the last line should be + 3*(1/4)^6

Comment: @trueblueanil could you edit it to show me? I indeed had 3*(1/4)^6

Comment: only the sign needs to be changed, from - 3*(1/4)^6 to + 3*(1/4)^6.

Comment: how about now, @trueblueanil ?

Comment: sorry, i'm not very familiar with the editing facilities here, it wanted at least 6 characters.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by inclusion-exclusion.

The probability that at most three suits are represented is $$4\times\left({3\over4}\right)^6$$ because there are $4$ ways to pick three suits and then $3/4$ chance any given card is from one of the three suits.

Probability of at most two suits is $$6\times\left({1\over2}\right)^6$$ and probability of at most one suit is $$4\times\left({1\over4}\right)^6$$

Now, do you know how to combine these to get the answer you are after?

Comment: i think general addition rule will combile them...

Comment: no im not able to combine them...

Comment: I may have made things too difficult. It now seems to me that you just subtract the probability of at most three suits from $1$, but I can't think about it now. Sorry.

Comment: you did not add in the complement of the cases. I have submitted my answer for your reference.